# How to provide a polyfill to a node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, polyfills

I'm trying to use the unsplash-js module in a NodeJS/express server. As the docs say: "This library depends on fetch to make requests to the Unsplash API. For environments that don't support fetch, you'll need to provide a polyfill". 
I've tried something like that, which I am quite ashamed of showing, but for the sake of learning I will

```
const Unsplash = require('unsplash-js').default;
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

Unsplash.prototype.fetch = fetch;

const unsplash = new Unsplash({
  applicationId: process.env.UNSPLASH_API_KEY,
});
```

And also this

```
Node.prototype.fetch = fetch;
```

But of course, nothing worked.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set fetch to global variable like below:

```
global.fetch = require('node-fetch')
```

Comment: ugh, this solves OP's problem, but doesn't answer OP's question, so it's of no use to people who want to learn how to do polyfills.